# Number rows for each unique value using arrayformula in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

```
A    B
DOG  1
DOG  2
DOG  3
DOG  4
CAT  1
CAT  2
BIRD 1
```

B1 is where the formula goes.

I'm trying to use arrayformula to number each row that contains the same value in column A. The number should change when the value changes. I was trying to use countif and indirect but it seems indirect doesn't work with arrayformula.

Comment: Could you post the formula you have tried?

Comment: I tried something like =ArrayFormula(countif(A1: indirect("A"&row(A1:A7)),"="&indirect("A"&row(A1:A7)))) but I really have no idea

Comment: Without an `ARRAYFORMULA` a simple `COUNTIF` `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,"="&$A2)` in B2 and drag down

Comment: I'm trying to automate the sheet so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way to do this type of cumulative count is with a countifs() using ROW() as a second parameter.  So in B1, you would put:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A="",,COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A)))
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Can you teach me what condition I need to add to reset the count to 1 when the same value appears again? For example, in "DOG DOG DOG CAT DOG" the last (4th) DOG should count from 1 again.

Comment: Playing about with this, I came up with =ArrayFormula(if(A:A="",,{1;row(A2:A)-iferror(match(row(A2:A),if(A2:A<>A1:A999,row(A2:A))),0)})) but I think really it's a separate question.

Comment: @ForMemo I can do that, but would need a sample sheet to work off of, doing it in the abstract is too tough.

Comment: @MattKing, could you explain how this part works: COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A)). Maybe separately COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A) and COUNTIFS(ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A)). Thank you very much.